# In the Steinhardt's bouncing cosmology, how would the CMB differ for patches close to pre-existing black holes

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

In Steinhardt's bouncing cosmology model, during the contraction phase the Hubble radius shrinks to microscopic sizes, although the overall contraction of the universe is much less significant. Each patch of space subsequently undergoes normal expansion, and typically should display properties similar to our CMB.

However, what happens to patches of space near horizons of pre-existing black holes, would the power spectrum of their CMB not be scale invariant?